# Linear composition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

can you help me with this quest?

About composition $f$ and vector space $\mathbf{V}=\mathbb{Z^4_2}$ we know the following:

$f \circ f = id_V$,$~~f $
$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\ 
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\ 
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}\right)
$,
$~~f $
$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0\\
1\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1\\ 
1\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}\right)
$

$id_V$ is identity.

Find $f~((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T).$

I would be gratefull for any kind of advice.

Thanks

Comment: $\Bbb Z_4^2$? Are you sure you're not in a vector space over a field, say $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: I am sorry, I always do something wrong, it should be $\mathbb{Z}^4_2$…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given values of $f$ on two vectors; the fact that $f\circ f = id_V$ should allow you to get values of $f$ on two additional vectors. Now you know what $f$ does to four vectors in a four-dimensional vector space; that is (typically) enough information to specify $f$ completely. In particular, if you can write a vector $\vec x$ as a linear combination of those four vectors, then you should be able to evaluate $f(\vec x)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote the wrong field but I guess the point is the same…?

Comment: Yes, the relevant four vectors are linearly independent over any field, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis $(1,0,1,0)^T,(1,1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0,1)^T,(1,1,0,1)^T$ is
$$
\pmatrix{
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0
}
$$